# Spring Security ignores successHandler and failureHandler

Tags: java, spring-security

I'm moving my Spring Security's configuration from xml to Java Config.
However for some reason when I try to use a custom sucessHandler or failureHandler spring just ignores them. Am I missing something?

I've looked a lot of examples over internet but can't find what is wrong with this configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(concurrentFilter, ConcurrentSessionFilter.class)
        .addFilterAfter(myFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .sessionManagement()
        .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(sessionAuthenticationStrategy());

    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .accessDecisionManager(accessDecisionManager())

        .antMatchers("/login.xhtml").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/403.xhtml").access("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")   
        .antMatchers("/wrecked-db.xhtml").access("ROLE_USER")   
        .antMatchers("/admin.xhtml").access("ROLE_ADMIN")   

        .antMatchers("/**.xhtml").access("NO_ACCESS")

        .and().formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
        .successHandler(customAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler)
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")

        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout.xhtml")
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml")
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")

        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedHandler(customAccessDeniedHandler);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took yours and modified a little and this one working fine for me,

```
http
  .csrf().disable()
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/403.xhtml").access("IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY")   
  .antMatchers("/wrecked-db.xhtml").access("ROLE_USER")   
  .antMatchers("/admin.xhtml").access("ROLE_ADMIN")   
  .antMatchers("/**.xhtml").access("NO_ACCESS")
  .antMatchers("/login*").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated()
  .and().formLogin()
  .loginPage("/login.html")
  .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
  .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
          System.out.println("AuthenticationSuccessHandler");

      }
  })
  .failureHandler(new AuthenticationFailureHandler() {
      @Override
      public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
          System.out.println("AuthenticationFailureHandler");

      }
  })
  .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout.xhtml")
  .logoutSuccessUrl("/login.xhtml")
  .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID");
```

And my login page will be like

```
<form action="login" method='POST'>
    <table>
       <tr>
          <td>UN</td>
          <td><input type='text' name='username' value=''></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td>Pass</td>
          <td><input type='password' name='password' /></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your efforts :)
I was able to solve this.

The problem was at this line  .addFilterAfter(myFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)

this "myFilter()" was overriding the config somehow.
Once I declared my customHandlers in the filter they started to work.

Not sure if I can answer my own question with this information though.

But again, thanks!